# MOSS custom search on new scope returns no results

Tags: 2007, search, search-scope

I configured a new search scope in MOSS and it returns results from the default search web parts, if I include the new scope in them.

When I try to query the scope from custom code, it doesn't return results. This behaviour is different from one server to another server.

If the default search web parts return results from my new scope and not from a custom web part (Prod), but that custom search web part return results in a different environment (Dev), what can be the problem? I know the configuration is ok, because I do get crawled results fro default web parts, I know that web part also works in dev, I'm not sure why it doesn't work in production if the Search Services are named the same and the search scope is named the same...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the metadata mapped properties.
Even though the main search was returning results, my metadata properties where not properly mapped and not getting the values when crawling, and because of this my query to the scope was not returning results.

Changing the mapped properties and re-crawling the content source solved it.